# Destructure array in function call

Tags: javascript

let's say I have the following array:

```
const arr = ["var1", "var2", "var3"];
```

and I have a function that takes strings as an arguments (but not ***array of*** strings):

```
func(var1, var2, var3)
```

so I tried:
`func(...arr)` and `func(arr.map((elem) => elem))` but obviously both of them return array so they can't  be passed to the function. The only method I know is by assigning them first:

```
const [var1, var2, var3] = ["var1", "var2", "var3"];
```

but it gets ugly if there are more variables in the array.
Is there any method that could achieve that?

Comment: I think you should re-try the `...foo` destructuring operator, as it should do what you're asking. Do you get an error or something from doing that?

Comment: `func(...arr)` - this should work. Could you provide a runnable example?

Comment: I think the `func(...arr)` should work.

Comment: Which browser/version are you using? could be an old version that doesn't [implement destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#browser_compatibility)

Comment: _“but obviously both of them return array”_ — How do you conclude that? What they return depends on what `func` itself returns.

Comment: `func(...arr.map((elem) => elem  + "hey"))` should also work

Comment: `func(...arr)` does actually work and it is 100% on me. I could have get the errors wrong and instantly thought that `...arr` was the issue. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine

```js
const arr = ["var1", "var2", "var3"];

func(...arr)

function func(var1, var2, var3) {
  console.log(var1, var2, var3)
}
```

Comment: It does indeed work, I must've gotten the errors wrong and thought that `...arr` is the issue. Thanks!